# For a positive real sequence, is $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R_+}$ be a sequence of real positive numbers such that the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty
$$
is convergent.

Is it true that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} 
\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n
=0
$$
Thanks.

Comment: $\infty$ isn't a number. You cant sum up to infinity from another infinity. It makes no sense.

Comment: @JaideepKhare that symbol means that the series is convergent in fact there's $<$ and not $=$

Comment: I am not talking about that inequality, I am talking about your question i.e. $$
\lim_{m \to \infty} 
\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n
=0
$$

Comment: i don't understand where's the problem @JaideepKhare

Comment: Do you mean : $$ \lim_{t \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=m}^t a_n =0 ~~ , t>m$$

Comment: i don't 'mean' but it is so

Comment: No it isn't. Infinite summation means summing up to $n$ and then applying limit $n \to \infty$. That's why I said infinity isn't just a number.

Comment: i prefer don't speak to you @JaideepKhare

Comment: @jadeep Khare: for fixed $ m \in \mathbb N$ the series $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n $ is convergent. Do you agree ? Fine ! Then let $r_m:=\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n $ . In this way we get a sequence $(r_m)_{m \ge 1}$. The question was: do we have $r_m \to 0$ for $m \to \infty$ ?. The answer is: yes !

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $s_n:=a_1+a_2+....a_n$.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ means that $(s_n)$ is convergent.

Let $s:= \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n$.

Then: $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n=s-s_{m-1} \to s-s=0$ for $m \to \infty$.