# Proof for squashed to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say I have a sequence of positive numbers $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. I know that the sum of all numbers is bounded by some constant, i.e. it holds $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < C$$ for some constant $C$. Now I inspect $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ and let $k$ grow to infinity. My intuition it tells me that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$$ must be zero because $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ is being "squashed" towards $C$ and cannot exceed $C$, but I cannot show this formally. Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n < \infty$, what can be said about $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382150/if-a-n-geq-0-forall-n-in-mathbbn-and-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-infty)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2210075/42969

Comment: Yes thank you and sorry for the duplicate, I didn't see the other discussions.